CORS Issue on Azure Function App (Flex Consumption Host Model)
I'm currently facing a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue with my Azure Function App, which is running on a Flex Consumption host model. It was developed locally and deployed to a Azure. I'm encountering the following error when trying to call the function from the protal:
HTTP response code: 0 Unknown HTTP error
HTTP response content: Error: {"message":"Failed to fetch","stack":"TypeError: Failed to fetch\n    at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/qTMV9j3qzPmv.js:227:24350","isError":true}
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Enabled CORS in Azure Portal in both Azure Function App and Azure Storage Account (Blob and File service - GET,POST,PUT allowed methods)
Verified the settings in the "Configuration" section under "Settings" in the Azure portal
Tried Incognito Mode


Do you have Access restrictions enabled in Azure function App?

Access restrictions might be enabled in our Azure Function App. This occurred while I was working on a client's project, so it's possible that specific restrictions or configurations were applied based on the project's requirements.

Check if below solution helps to resolve the issue.

This error occurs if the access restrictions is enabled in the Azure function App.

Enable access to all networks or grant access from Ip Address or virtual network.



Configure CORS to allow origins:

Portal:

After enabling network access, able to run the function.


